# Is the following grammar is ambiguous and if it is What's the unambiguous grammar of the following

Tags: ambiguous-grammar

```
E-->I/E+E/E-E/E*E/E/E
I-->a/b/Ia/Ib/I0/I1
```

I know how to remove ambiguity for the productions of `E` but the presence of `I` is making me confuse to solve the ambiguity